# Как определить дочерние элементы родительского элемента по значению? SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, рекурсия, group-by, дерево

Доброго времени суток! Необходимо сделать группировку по дочерним элементам, родитель которых имеет значение `need` (смотри скрин ниже). Как это сделать при помощи рекурсивного запроса WITH?

Имеющиеся данные:

```
+-----+----------+----------+
| id  | parentid | selector |
+-----+----------+----------+
|  1  | null     |          |
|  2  | 1        |          |
|  3  | 1        | need     |
|  4  | 2        |          |
|  5  | 2        | need     |
|  6  | 3        |          |
|  7  | 5        |          |
|  8  | 5        |          |
|  9  | 6        |          |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Необходим результат:

```
+-----+----------+----------+----------------+
| id  | parentid | selector | parentSelector |
+-----+----------+----------+----------------+
|  1  | null     |          | null           |
|  2  | 1        |          | null           |
|  3  | 1        | need     | 3              |
|  4  | 2        |          | null           |
|  5  | 2        | need     | 5              |
|  6  | 3        |          | 3              |
|  7  | 5        |          | 5              |
|  8  | 5        |          | 5              |
|  9  | 6        |          | 3              |
+-----+----------+----------+----------------+
```

По сути нужно создать еще одни столбец, в котором каждому дочернему проставлять id предка со значением `need`. Тогда получится сгруппировать узлы. Быть может есть другой способ решения данной задачи?

Использую `SQL Server 2012`

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Навскидку будет что-то вроде

```
WITH CTE (id, parentid, selector, parentSelector)
AS 
(
SELECT id, parentid, selector,
       CASE WHEN selector='need' THEN id 
            ELSE NULL END parentSelector
FROM datatable
WHERE parentid IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT dt.id, dt.parentid, dt.selector,
       CASE WHEN dt.selector='need' THEN dt.id 
            WHEN CTE.parentSelector IS NOT NULL THEN CTE.parentSelector
            ELSE NULL END parentSelector
FROM datatable dt
INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.id = dt.parentid
)
```

Comment: + `SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY id`

Comment: @Akina, 4per, Благодарю! Сейчас попробую написать запрос к своей таблице

Comment: @4per Я ориентировался на желание автора что-то там группировать - потому и опустил собственно запросную часть, показав только подготовку данных.

Comment: Да, в этом была боль :) Все получилось, спасибо! И если группировать по задумке, то ORDER BY parentSelector. Тут уже неточно сформулировал задачу...

Comment: @Akina, подскажи пожалуйста, как избавиться от дубликатов, образующихся в случае, если перед элементом со значением 'need' есть еще несколько пустых элементов? В этом случае в результат попадает пустой узел и узел со значением 'need'. Distinct оставляет их оба. Тут можно было бы сделать проверку в условии на пустоту, но нужно оставить пустой узел, в случае, если у его цепочки нет значений 'need'.

Comment: @Akina, кажется, разобрался. В основном запросе, где "LEFT JOIN CTE", добавил "and CTE.parentSelector_id is not null". Вроде стал извлекать нужные записи. Еще протестирую. Спасибо!